# How to add HomeView from Main.dart with MVVM?

Tags: flutter

I have an AlertDialog in main.dart. I want to take some information from this Dialog and add it to the HomeViewModel. There is no problem during the first load with the default elements, but when I want to add elements later, notifyListeners does not work.

How can I add HomeView correctly in main.dart while adhering to MVVM?

**HomeViewModel**

```
    class HomeViewModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<ViewItemModel> get view => _view;

  void addView(ViewItemModel view) {
    _view.add(view);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void removeView(int index) {
    _view.removeAt(index);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

**HomeView**

```
HomeViewModel _viewModel = HomeViewModel();

class HomeView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeViewState createState() => _HomeViewState();
}

class _HomeViewState extends State<HomeView> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Wrap(
                  children: [
                    ..._viewModel.view.map(buildContainer).toList(),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildContainer(item) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3),
      child: GestureDetector(
        child: Container(
          height: 180,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2 - 20,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: item.color,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
          ),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              SvgPicture.asset(
                item.icon,
                width: 35,
                height: 35,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 5,
              ),
              Opacity(
                opacity: 0.5,
                child: Text(
                  item.title,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                      fontSize: 16,
                      color: Colors.black),
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                item.minute.toString(),
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    fontSize: 36,
                    color: Colors.black),
              ),
              Text(
                "min",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    fontSize: 11,
                    color: Colors.black),
              ),
              item.second > 0
                  ? Text(
                      "+" + item.second.toString() + " seconds",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                          fontSize: 11,
                          color: Colors.black),
                    )
                  : Text(
                      "",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                          fontSize: 11,
                          color: Colors.black),
                    )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        onTap: () {},
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Main.dart Add Button

```
   Expanded(
                      child: FilledButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            print("Name : " + _nameController.text);
                            print("Minute : " + selectedMinute.toString());
                            print("Second : " + selectedSecond.toString());
                            print("Color : " + selectedColorIndex.toString());
                            print("Icon : " + selectedIconIndex.toString());

                            setState(() {
                              _homeViewModel.addView(new ViewItemModel(
                                  icons[selectedIconIndex],
                                  _nameController.text,
                                  colors[selectedColorIndex],
                                  selectedMinute.toInt(),
                                  selectedSecond.toInt()));
                            });
                          },
                          child: Text("Create"))),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it would appear that your `HomeView` Widget is not listening for changes. When you first instantiate the widget with the initial value of the change notifier, it will work, but then the widget isn't listening for changes.

Try to wrap your widget with a `ListenableBuilder` like so:

```dart
ListenableBuilder( 
  listenable: _viewModel,
  builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
    return Wrap(
      children: _viewModel.view.map(buildContainer).toList(),
    );
  }),
),
```

Full context with edit:

```dart
HomeViewModel _viewModel = HomeViewModel();

class HomeView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeViewState createState() => _HomeViewState();
}

class _HomeViewState extends State<HomeView> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: ListenableBuilder( // Start edit
                  listenable: _viewModel,
                  builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
                    return Wrap(
                      children: _viewModel.view.map(buildContainer).toList(),
                    );
                  }),
                ), // \End Edit
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildContainer(item) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3),
      child: GestureDetector(
        child: Container(
          height: 180,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2 - 20,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: item.color,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
          ),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              SvgPicture.asset(
                item.icon,
                width: 35,
                height: 35,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 5,
              ),
              Opacity(
                opacity: 0.5,
                child: Text(
                  item.title,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                      fontSize: 16,
                      color: Colors.black),
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                item.minute.toString(),
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    fontSize: 36,
                    color: Colors.black),
              ),
              Text(
                "min",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    fontSize: 11,
                    color: Colors.black),
              ),
              item.second > 0
                  ? Text(
                      "+" + item.second.toString() + " seconds",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                          fontSize: 11,
                          color: Colors.black),
                    )
                  : Text(
                      "",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                          fontSize: 11,
                          color: Colors.black),
                    )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        onTap: () {},
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

That should enable the Wrap widget to be rebuilt whenever your _viewModel is updated through notifyListeners().

Just bear in mind that it may have some performance implications if you are expecting a truly massive list that requires your `buildContainer` function to be called for each element in the list on every update. But for small lists you should be good!